# cannot associate .db extension to my app

Tags: android, android-intent, filter

I'm trying to associate .db file extension to my app.

I've put this code in my manifest file, but android does not suggest to use my app to open/view/edit the file (as attachment or file in an explorer)

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Cookie.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.db"
                />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.db"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Can you help me please ?
Thanks.
Seb

Comment: try adding `<data android:scheme="file" />` and removing `android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"`

Comment: it does not work. Sorry.